# Spaces trimmed automatically [2spaces = 5spaces]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I tried the following query (test data) and found **`SPACES trimmed automatically`**.

```
DECLARE @Employees TABLE(EmpID INT IDENTITY(1,1), FirstName VARCHAR(10), LastName VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @Employees VALUES
('Mani','  '),
('Muthu','Kumar'),
('Ram','Prasath'),
('Elango',''),
('Prabhu','     ')

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(10) = '  ' -- 2 Spaces

-- SELECT LEN(@Name)  -- 0

-- Returned rows with empty LastName
SELECT * FROM @Employees WHERE LastName = @Name

-- Update - Multiple spaces
UPDATE @Employees SET LastName = NULLIF(LastName, '  ') -- All empty last name updated

SELECT * FROM @Employees
```

In the above example, I searched rows `LastName with 2 spaces`. But it returned **all rows with Empty LastName**. I checked the length of the given parameter value. And it shows `0 (actually 6 spaces)`.

I tried to update LastName which contains more than one space (in example, tried 2 spaces), but it *`updated all the records with empty LastName`*

> **How the automatic trim happening?**

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) [`LEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190329.aspx) is documented as:

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks.**

(**my emphasis**)

and 2) [How SQL Server compares strings with trailing spaces](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626) is documented:

> The ANSI standard requires padding for the character strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings **'abc'** and **'abc '** to be equivalent for most comparison operations.
>
> ...

(And so, in fact, technically what happens is not trimming but padding. Bonus points if you can actually work out a way to demonstrate this difference)

---

Two ways to work with these features - one, you can use [`DATALENGTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173486.aspx). The other is that you can append a trailing non-space character, to use as a sentinel.

Comment: I tried with `DATALENGTH` in update statement... It is working fine... Thanks for your useful information.