# SQL - string comparison ignores space

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

This query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'abc ' = 'abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Returns 1, even though 'abc ' clearly is not equal to 'abc'. Similarly,

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'abc ' LIKE '%c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Also returns 1. However, a very similar query:

```
SELECT * FROM #tempTable WHERE Name LIKE '%c'
```

Did not return a row where Name = 'abc '.

SQL Server 2008 R2, Windows 7 & 2008 R2, x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the Name column was `NVARCHAR` (even though it contained ASCII characters only) and `NVARCHAR` behaves differently than `VARCHAR`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN N'abc ' LIKE 'abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Returns 0, ditto for column instead of literal. The following does return 1 still:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN N'abc ' = 'abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

So `=` and `LIKE` work differently, another peculiar difference.

PS. For posterity, here are some examples:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN 'abc ' = 'abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
-- 1
SELECT CASE WHEN 'abc ' LIKE 'abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
-- 1
SELECT CASE WHEN 'abc ' LIKE '%c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
-- 1
SELECT CASE WHEN N'abc ' = N'abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
-- 1
SELECT CASE WHEN N'abc ' LIKE N'abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
-- 0
SELECT CASE WHEN N'abc ' LIKE N'%c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
-- 0

CREATE TABLE #tempTable (Name VARCHAR(30));
INSERT #tempTable VALUES ('abc ');
SELECT * FROM #tempTable WHERE Name = 'abc';
-- returns row
SELECT * FROM #tempTable WHERE Name LIKE 'abc';
-- returns row
SELECT * FROM #tempTable WHERE Name LIKE '%c';
-- returns row
SELECT * FROM #tempTable WHERE Name LIKE N'%c';
-- does not return row

CREATE TABLE #tempTable2 (Name NVARCHAR(30));
INSERT #tempTable2 VALUES (N'abc ');
SELECT * FROM #tempTable2 WHERE Name = N'abc';
-- returns row
SELECT * FROM #tempTable2 WHERE Name LIKE N'abc';
-- does not return row
SELECT * FROM #tempTable2 WHERE Name LIKE '%c';
-- does not return row
SELECT * FROM #tempTable2 WHERE Name LIKE N'%c';
-- does not return row
```

Comment: If I run that on my machine, it still returns 1. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25242918/15498) for some actual explanation of what's happening and further reading.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Please see updated answer. Turns out `=` and `LIKE` work differently (for the same operands without masks like `%`).

Comment: @Mr.TA Yes, `=` and `like` work differently, but that is well documented and not peculiar. You could say it is peculiar that `'abc ' like 'abc'` returns 1, but `'abc' like 'abc '` returns 0 - but that is also well known.

Comment: @Mr.TA - Yes, so the code in your answer when I replied was incorrect, this has nothing to do with `nvarchar` vs `varchar` and is documented in the links in the answer I pointed you towards.

Comment: @GSerg sure it's well known to some, and documented somewhere, said documentation having been read by some. However, not all people know everything, hence the point of this Q&A. I, for one, didn't know this before having to deal with this. If questions which are known to anybody or are documented anywhere, do not belong here, please arrange for it to be deleted - along with 99.99% of all other questions on this site.

Answer (score 7):

= ignores trailing space
len ignores trailing space
like does not ignore trailing space

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'abc ' = 'abc' and DATALENGTH('abc ') =  DATALENGTH('abc') 
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

You can assert DATALENGTH is not relevant but it is still the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compare things in this way but are restricted because your columns are of data type VARCHAR, something like this will basically fill the trailing space with an 'X' which will accomplish a failed comparison:

```
DECLARE @1 VARCHAR(5), @2 VARCHAR(5)
SET @1 = 'ABC '
SET @2 = 'ABC'

IF REPLACE(@1,' ','X') = REPLACE(@2,' ','X')    
    PRINT 'Equal'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Not Equal'
```

Not rocket science, but at least a work around if you encounter a similar situation that you need to deal with  :)

Comment: Good suggestion, I sometimes do `@x + 'X' = @y + 'X'` or `LEN(@x + 'X')`, which I think is faster than `REPLACE`.

Answer (score 0):

TA, I am not sure how you got zero by simply mentioning as unicode(N). I run your query and it giving me 1 only.

You can compare the LEN('abc ') and DATALENGTH('abc ') and can use those as per you requirement or you can replace the trailing space with some character to solve your problem.

Comment: Please see updated answer. Also, `LEN` and `DATALENGTH` are not directly relevant to my problem with equality.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a nvarchar column and wanted to fix the data so I did the following to find the data

```
select 'x' + username + 'x'  from aspnet_users 
where 'x' + username + 'x' <> 'x' + rtrim(username) + 'x'
```

The where clause compares the username as is with the trimmed version

```
'x1234 x' <> 'x1234x'
```

To fix the data I just did an update

```
update aspnet_Users
set username = rtrim(username)
where 'x' + username + 'x' <> 'x' + rtrim(username) + 'x'
```